# How to get the GAP of a pyomo model running with Gurobi solver?

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I usually use: 'results.Solver()['Gap']' for CBC, SCIP... but I'm not being able to get the gap value solving my pyomo model with Gurobi, using last pyomo version 6.6.2.

I found there is a gap item by running 'results.Solution.items()':
dict_items([('**Gap**', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf70790>), ('Status', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf714b0>), ('Message', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf71480>), ('Problem', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at
0x7f1bccf71660>), ('Objective', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf71630>), ('Variable', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf71600>), ('Constraint', <pyomo.opt.results.container.ScalarData object at 0x7f1bccf715d0>)])
(

But, when I try to get the value by running 'results.Solution.gap' it shows:

How could I get my model gap value?